# Bash script exiting prematurely when calling another script inside it

Tags: bash

I have a bash script which calls another bash script, like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
./script-two.sh
echo "Hello!"
```

The problem that I have is that it never makes it to printing "Hello!"

I think this is because ./script-two.sh (Which I did not write) is somehow exiting or changing the shell. I have included this script at the end of this post.

Is there a way I can gurentee that my execution will continue after script-two.sh executes?

I have looked into using the trap command, but I don't fully understand its use properly.

Thanks,

Casey

Here is the contents of what would be script-two.sh

```
    #!/bin/sh
#  This file is part of the DITA Open Toolkit project hosted on 
#  Sourceforge.net. See the accompanying license.txt file for 
#  applicable licenses.
#  (c) Copyright IBM Corp. 2006 All Rights Reserved.

export DITA_HOME=cwd


if  [ "${DITA_HOME:+1}" != "1" ]; then 
   echo "DITA_HOME environment variable is empty or not set";
   exit 127;
fi

echo $DITA_HOME

cd "$DITA_HOME"

# Get the absolute path of DITAOT's home directory
DITA_DIR="`pwd`"

echo $DITA_DIR

if [ -f "$DITA_DIR"/tools/ant/bin/ant ] && [ ! -x "$DITA_DIR"/tools/ant/bin/ant ]; then
chmod +x "$DITA_DIR"/tools/ant/bin/ant
fi

export ANT_OPTS="-Xmx512m $ANT_OPTS"
export ANT_OPTS="$ANT_OPTS -Djavax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory=net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl"
export ANT_HOME="$DITA_DIR"/tools/ant
export PATH="$DITA_DIR"/tools/ant/bin:"$PATH"

NEW_CLASSPATH="$DITA_DIR/lib:$DITA_DIR/lib/dost.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/commons-codec-1.4.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/resolver.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/icu4j.jar"
NEW_CLASSPATH="$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-dom.jar:$NEW_CLASSPATH"
NEW_CLASSPATH="$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-dom4j.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-jdom.jar:$NEW_CLASSPATH"
NEW_CLASSPATH="$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-s9api.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-sql.jar:$NEW_CLASSPATH"
NEW_CLASSPATH="$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-xom.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-xpath.jar:$DITA_DIR/lib/saxon/saxon9-xqj.jar:$NEW_CLASSPATH"
if test -n "$CLASSPATH"
then
export CLASSPATH="$NEW_CLASSPATH":"$CLASSPATH"
else
export CLASSPATH="$NEW_CLASSPATH"
fi

"$SHELL"
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like `script-two.sh` is setting up an ant build environment.

I think the author intended that it sets up the build environment, then you type your build commands in manually, then type `exit` to leave the build environment.

I say this because the bottom line of `script-two.sh` is:

```
"$SHELL"
```

which starts a new shell.

Try running your script, then type `exit`.  I think you will see it print `Hello!` after you type `exit`.

---

I'm guessing you're trying to do something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
./script-two.sh
ant <some args>
```

To do that, what you really want to do is source it, by changing:

```
./script-two.sh
```

to

```
. script-two.sh
```

e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
. script-two.sh
ant <some args>
```

But, you will need to edit `script-two.sh` and change:

```
"$SHELL"
```

to:

```
case $0 in *script-two.sh)
    # executed, start a new shell with the new environment
    "$SHELL" 
    ;;
*)
    # sourced, don't start a new shell
    ;;
esac
```

so that it only starts a shell if the script is being run like `./script-two.sh`, but not if it is being sourced like `. script-two.sh`.

Or if you absolutely can't change `script-two.sh`, then you could do:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
. script-two.sh </dev/null
ant <some args>
```

which will trick `"$SHELL"` into exiting because it has no input.

---

Also

```
export DITA_HOME=cwd
```

doesn't seem right to me.

It should probably be

```
export DITA_HOME=$(pwd)
```

or

```
export DITA_HOME=`pwd`
```

(both are equivalent)

Comment: Thank you, this worked great. I think you are also right about the problems inside script-two.sh but I didn't write that and can't change the code.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem today, up on digging I finally found the answer.

The script I was calling (from within my script) actually had an exit 0 in the end. Removing that fixed my issues.

Just leaving this here as someone may find it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters, you can execute your bash script with the -x switch to see where it is failing:

```
bash -x script-one.sh
```

Secondly, if you call the second script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Hi"
var=$(bash script-two.sh)
echo "Hello!"
```

It will continue, as long as script-two.sh exits cleanly.  Again, you can run the -x script against that script find any problems.

And as Mikel mentioned, always make sure to have `exit` at the bottom of your scripts.

Comment: I don't think Mikel said anything about having `exit` at the bottom of your scripts; he was simply suggesting it as a mechanism to exit the shell started by `script-two.sh`.